# Seam - Entity Query - dynamic restrictions

Tags: jpa, seam, restrictions, seam-gen

I have an EntityQuery - `addressList` generated by Seam-gen for Entity `Address`.

Lets say that address has following fields : `streetName` and `city`, so Seam-gen generate restrictions for them.

I would like to extend my EntityQuery with a following restrictions:
I have a field 'keyVal' which can be set in faces context with `#{addressList.keyVal}`.
Lets supose that `keyVal` is `aaa bbb ccc`. Now the query should add restrictions which will be used to find all entities with:

```
streetName like '%aaa%' or  streetName like '%bbb%' or streetName like '%ccc%' 
 or city like '%aaa%' or  city like '%bbb%' or city like '%ccc%'
```

Do you have any suggestions how to achieve this? I am really stucked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is EntityQuery does not support multiple value bindings on restrictions. See
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBSEAM-1065

You can work around this sometimes by creative use of your criteria class.

You can sometimes look at modifying the query. For example, if I have a single staffName input and I need to query where staff first name like the input OR staff last name like input, I can write my query like this:

```
private static final String[] RESTRICTIONS = {
    "lower(concat(s.firstName, concat(' ', s.lastName))) like concat('%', 
               concat(lower(#{criteria.staffName}), '%'))"};
```

Hopefully this gives you some ideas.

Comment: Maybe you know if i am able to get the value of some context parameter(in my case '#{addressList.keyVal}'). I could then override getEjbql() method and add some restrictions based on value...